# How to restrict Input box input to date only

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to implement a control in the code below to only allow dates with mm/dd/yyyy format and to prevent blanks from being entered in the input box. I've tried adding some code but keep running into errors. The first control to check if it's blank works, but the second if Not seems to just be skipped.

```
'Updates the report date located in report generation tab cell B8
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Report Generation")
ReTry:
With ws1
    Dim rptdate As Variant
        rptdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Report Date *Must be EOM format mm/dd/yyyy*", "Enter Date")
        If rptdate = "" Then
        MsgBox ("You did not enter a date!"), vbCritical, Error
        GoTo ReTry
        If Not IsDate(rptdate) Then
        MsgBox ("You did not enter the correct format!"), vbCritical, Error
        GoTo ReTry
        End If
        Else
        Range("B8").Value = rptdate
        End If
End With
```

Comment: Try `elseif` instead?

Comment: do you know where exactly? running into issues if i replace the first if by elseif or the second one.

Comment: ah got it! I added it to the second if after looking up the elseif syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your If statements are a little off for this. Here's a code that will remove the use of `GoTo` (which is best practice), and still loop correctly until you get the format you want.

```
Sub tt()
Dim ws1     As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Report Generation")

With ws1
    Dim rptdate As Variant
    rptdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Report Date *Must be EOM format mm/dd/yyyy*", "Enter Date")

    Do While rptdate = "" Or Not IsDate(rptdate)
        MsgBox ("You did not enter a date in the correct format!"), vbCritical, Error
        rptdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Report Date *Must be EOM format mm/dd/yyyy*", "Enter Date")
    Loop

    .Range("B8").Value = rptdate
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution I posted above seems to work as well using elseif rather than two independent if statements.
rpt date should be added once a date in format mm/dd/yyyy is entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

The below accurately does what I wanted. Thanks findwindow.

```
'Updates the report date located in report generation tab cell B8
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets("Report Generation")
ReTry:
With ws1
Dim rptdate As Variant
    rptdate = InputBox("Please Enter the Report Date *Must be EOM format mm/dd/yyyy*", "Enter Date")
    If rptdate = "" Then
    MsgBox ("You did not enter a date!"), vbCritical, Error
    GoTo ReTry
    ElseIf Not IsDate(rptdate) Then
    MsgBox ("You did not enter the correct format!"), vbCritical, Error
    GoTo ReTry
    Else
    Range("B8").Value = rptdate
    End If
End With
```

Comment: See my edit in my post for a solution that avoids `GoTo` (which is best practice for VB). It also cuts the length down a bit.

Comment: Using `GoTo` should be reserved for very few cases (`On Error GoTo ErrHandler` being one), in VBA and most programming languages from what I've seen.  If you have many macros using `GoTo`, it's really, really worth reading up on how to avoid them with `If/Then`, `Do While`, or `Do Until`, etc. loops.  (I also realize I forgot to add the `Range"B8").Value = rptdate` in my edit, but I have added that in to the end).