# Getting date from an InputBox

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am working on an Excel VBA by a button. After clicking the button, an input box will pop out and ask the User what the next month is. Enter the date of the new month will create a new workbook named with the month and year. It works fine if the User enters the date properly. However, if the User enters nothing in the input box by cancelling it or entering other data instead of the date. Error code 13 would pop out: Type Mismatch. Seem like the DATE variable cannot be empty.

Here is my code:

```
Sub NewMonth_button()

Dim Date_Today As Date
Dim nwFilename As String

Date_Today = InputBox("Please enter YEAR-Month")

nwFilename = "Daily Journal_" & Year(Date_Today) & "_" & Month(Date_Today)

Worksheets(Array("list", "data", "Fill", "Archive>")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & nwFilename

End Sub
```

I have tried something like:

```
If Date_Today = "" then
exit sub
end if
```

Just after the line `Date_Today = InputBox("Please enter YEAR-Month")`
But it is not working.

Is there any method to avoid these?
Many thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049088/how-to-restrict-input-box-input-to-date-only

Comment: Also rather than using Inputbox or textbox to accept dates, you may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650417/how-can-i-create-a-calendar-input-in-vba-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```vb
Sub NewMonth_button()

    Dim Date_Today As Date
    Dim Date_Text  As String
    Dim nwFilename As String

    Date_Text = InputBox("Please enter YEAR-Month")
    If IsDate(Date_Text & "-01") Then
        Date_Today = DateValue(Date_Text & "-01")
        nwFilename = "Daily Journal_" & Format(Date_Today, "yyyy_mm")

        Worksheets(Array("list", "data", "Fill", "Archive>")).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & nwFilename
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works great. Simple and exactly what I need. I have learnt not only `IsDate` but also the `Format` function.  No need to use `Year(Date_Today) & "_" & Month(Date_Today)` anymore.

Comment: Surely `Format(Date_Today, "yyyy_mm")` not `Format(Date_Today & "yyyy_mm")`

Answer (score 1):

### Create Monthly Workbook

```vb
Sub CreateMonthlyWorkbook()
     
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create Monthly Workbook"
    Const DST_FILE_NAME_LEFT As String = "Daily Journal_"
    ' The following two need to be in sync:
    Const DST_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsx"
    Dim dFileFormat As XlFileFormat: dFileFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Dim dSheetNames() As Variant:
    dSheetNames = Array("list", "data", "Fill", "Archive>")
    Const PERIOD_DELIMITER As String = "-" ' single character!
    Const PERIOD_FILE_DELIMITER As String = "_"
    Const PERIOD_YEAR_FORMAT As String = "yyyy" ' fixed!
    Const PERIOD_MONTH_FORMAT As String = "m" ' or 'mm' fixed!
    Const YEAR_MIN As Long = 2001 ' Excel Min = 1900
    Const YEAR_MAX As Long = 2030 ' Excel Max = 9999
    Const MONTH_MIN As Long = 1
    Const MONTH_MAX As Long = 12
    
    ' Reference the source workbook.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Determine the destination folder path.
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = swb.Path
    
    ' Determine the input parameters.
    Dim PeriodFormat As String: PeriodFormat = PERIOD_YEAR_FORMAT _
        & PERIOD_DELIMITER & PERIOD_MONTH_FORMAT
    Dim iPrompt As String: iPrompt = "Please enter the period in """ _
        & PeriodFormat & """ format:"
    Dim iDefault As String: iDefault = Format(Date, PeriodFormat) ' current
       
    ' Input.
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
       
    Dim PeriodInput As Variant, PerLen As Long, DelPos As Long
    Dim YearValue As Variant, MonthValue As Variant, IsPeriodValid As Boolean
    
    Do
        ' Input.
        PeriodInput = Application _
            .InputBox(iPrompt, PROC_TITLE, iDefault, , , , , 2) ' 2 - string
        ' Canceled.
        If VarType(PeriodInput) = vbBoolean Then
            MsgBox "Canceled. Workbook not created.", _
                vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Not canceled.
        PerLen = Len(PeriodInput)
        If PerLen = 6 Or PerLen = 7 Then
            DelPos = InStr(PeriodInput, PERIOD_DELIMITER)
            If DelPos = 5 Then
                YearValue = Left(PeriodInput, 4)
                If YearValue Like "####" Then
                    YearValue = CLng(YearValue)
                    If YearValue >= YEAR_MIN And YearValue <= YEAR_MAX Then
                        MonthValue = Right(PeriodInput, PerLen - DelPos)
                        If MonthValue Like "#" Or MonthValue Like "##" Then
                            MonthValue = CLng(MonthValue)
                            If MonthValue >= MONTH_MIN _
                                    And MonthValue <= MONTH_MAX Then
                                IsPeriodValid = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until IsPeriodValid = True
    
    ' Build the destination file path.
    
    Dim DateString As String: DateString = YearValue & PERIOD_FILE_DELIMITER _
        & Format(MonthValue, String(Len(PERIOD_MONTH_FORMAT) - 1, "0") & "#")
    Dim dFileName As String:
    dFileName = DST_FILE_NAME_LEFT & DateString & DST_FILE_EXTENSION
    Dim dFilePath As String:
    dFilePath = dFolderPath & Application.PathSeparator & dFileName
    
    If Len(Dir(dFilePath)) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & dFileName & """ already exists in folder """ _
            & dFolderPath & """!", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Copy the sheets to a new workbook.
    swb.Sheets(dSheetNames).Copy
    
    ' Save (and close) the newly created workbook.
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        .SaveAs Filename:=dFilePath, FileFormat:=dFileFormat
        '.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Created workbook """ & dFileName & """ in folder """ _
            & dFolderPath & """.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: Grateful for your detailed codes. Although it is quite complicated for me, it gives me a lot of ideas.